# How to Resolve moviepy error in write_audiofile?

Tags: python, moviepy

Can someone please tell me why this error occurs while converting 'mp4' to 'mp3'? And also how to resolve this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pranjal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 200, in 
    codec = extensions_dict[ext[1:]]['codec'][0]
KeyError: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pranjal\Documents\Python\filemvidaud.py", line 14, in <module>
    au.audio.write_audiofile(b)
  File "<decorator-gen-45>", line 2, in write_audiofile
  File "C:\Users\Pranjal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration    
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\Pranjal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 202, in write_audiofile
    raise ValueError("MoviePy couldn't find the codec associated "
ValueError: MoviePy couldn't find the codec associated with the filename. Provide the 'codec' parameter in write_audiofile.
```